# How to place an absolutely positioned img at the top of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lenb/vLke49gu/1/).  It is my first, so I am not certain that it is correct but all the code from my small example is there.  Nothing cahnges when I run it.  On my machine, the click handler is called but I see no change to the position of the viewport.  That is the problem, I would like the image to move to the top of the viewport.

Hope this is a better question.

My original question is below:

I have a relatively positioned div that contains some absolute imgs.  I want this arrangement to appear at the top of the viewport.  I believe that if I can set the top of the div (position:relative) to the top to the viewport, the images it contains will come along.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to do this.  The relative div is at the bottom of the page, and when I click on it, I want the document to reposition so it is displayed at the top with its content.  I've tried scrollTop with large positive and negative numbers and I can't get the div to reposition.

I've been trying things like:

`$(#view2").scrollTop(xxx);`

With no luck.

My html looks like the following.  Everything but #view2 is absolute, #view2 is relative.  The content of #view1 is set dynamically.

```
<div id="view2">
    <img>
    <img>
        <div id="view1" ></div>
    <img>
    <img>
</div>
```

Comment: could you setup a jsfiddle / jsbin?

Comment: One suggestion would be to change the position of parent div to absolute and move it to the top on scroll. later change it back

Comment: expected results aren't exactly clear but it sounds like `position:fixed` is what you want. Expected behavior definitely needs some clarification and we have no idea what other page structure or css looks like

Comment: Failed to provide relevant code **-1**

Comment: Sorry, I had to walk away.  Lunch was burning.  I will make a jfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide some further it's pretty difficult to analyse your problem:

but scrollTop is used like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: elementToScrollTo.offset().top
},200);
```

the parent element of your *position absolute* container must have *position relative*.

As i said, it's difficult to answer without proper code snippets of yours

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your container element to sit at the top of your page then use:

```
#view2 {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Just an example - obviously if you didn't need padding etc just remove them, the above is just a typical use for a fixed header.